# Windows 10 is lagging

Tags: drivers, gui, lag, video-playback, windows-10-v1511

My Windows 10 sometimes gets lags. It's most annoying when I'm watching videos (YT/flash/disk - doesn't matter). It's look like a 0,5s screen pause and superfast foward to actual play state. I can notice it at Windows GUI too. In the beginning I tought it was a fail of Intel AHCI 5 Series driver. In depend of driver version, I noticed more or less number of lags and sound buzz, but at the standard Microsoft AHCI driver it happens too. By the way, at the Intel driver version number higher than 11.5.0.1184 the hibernation is not working properly - computer cut of the power when I'm waking it up after hibernation/fast shutdown.

Now I think It could be a problem with NVIDIA graphics driver. The problem exist at upgraded instalation and clean instalation of Windows 10. At Windows 7/8/8.1 everything was ok.

At Linux Mint instaled next to Windows everything is fine, so I think it's not a hardware problem.

**My computer:**

```
Windows 10 build 10586, 
Notebook Acer TravelMate 5742ZG, 
Intel Core i5 460M, NVIDIA GeForce 540M, SSD Samsung Evo 850, 4GB RAM.
```

Comment: If the problem exists with a clean installation, and I presume this problem did not exist on the Windows 10 installation until recently, what you describe cannot be a driver problem.  Just because the problem does not exist within the Mint installation currently, unless you are using the hardware in identical ways, that does tell us much.  "By the way, at the Intel driver" - Intel has not release, and will not release, Windows 10 compatible display drivers.  It also does not have Windows 8.1 display drivers either, so if you have Intel display drivers installed, remove them.

Comment: Post updated. I'm not using Intel graphics, only NVIDIA GeForce. Intel driver means Intel AHCI 5 Series driver. I noticed my problem few minutes after update from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10. I made clean installation of Windows 10  - problem stil exist. I installed fresh Windows 7 next to Windows 10 and Mint. After few hours of watching YouTube videos at Windows 7 everything is ok - no lags. So it's Windows 10 compatibility issue?

Comment: this sounds like it could be a throttling problem, maybe plug in the laptop and set the "when plugged in power plan" for CPU to 100% (at least for testing)

Comment: I setted min state for CPU at 100% and disabled core parking, no success - still lags :/ I notice it more at battery than when plugged in. Temperatures of components are fine.